# Is it possible to set ELB using juju charms?

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2, aws

I get several charms using jujucharms official website. but when i try to access `juju deploy aws-ec2-elb` error occurred. So is it possible to set elb using juju-core command line ?

Comment: "error occurred". And what is the reason for not including the error notice?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your reply. I error show that "charms not found"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for this:

- https://jujucharms.com/u/james-sapara/aws-ec2-elb/

Juju will only deploy things without a namespace, like `juju deploy foo` if the charm has been through rigorous testing and maintenance.

For this specific charm you'd have to add the person's username to deploy:

```
juju deploy cs:~james-sapara/precise/aws-ec2-elb-1
```

The charm's page on jujucharms.com will always have a command line snippet for you to copy and paste on the top right of each page.

Keep in mind that when you're deploying from a personal namespace that there's no guarantee that the charm is working or maintained, similar to how code is hosted on github or containers on the Docker Hub or other code hosting sites.